# Jenkins: Make build success dependent on tests

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, hudson, jmeter, soapui

I'm new to Jenkins/Hudson but I didn't find a plugin which provides the functionality I am looking for.

I want to make the build process of my web application dependent on multiple function tests I already implemented in JMeter and soapUI. So after the project is built, the tests should start. If they fail (to a certain amount), the whole build should fail (and not only the job containing the tests).

As I have read, post-build actions and JMeter/soapUI tests are not a problem. The only missing things seems to be the connection to the success of the whole build. Is there a plugin or a workaround for my requirements?

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the [Performance Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Performance+Plugin):

- Add a JMeter Report and define the path to your jtl files.
- To mark the build to status as failure you need to specify the `Failed threshold`.

Example:
If you specify a threshold of 20%: If 20% or more of your jmeter samples fail, the jenkins job is marked as failure.